# I want to draw a table like this, but my code does not work

Tags: multirow

[image]

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{colortbl,multirow,hhline}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.30980, 0.50588, 0.73725}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.82353, 0.87843, 0.92941}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]   % added on 12172013 for caption and label
\centering
\caption{Table}
\label{tb32b}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5em}|p{10.8cm}|p{3em}|}
\rowcolor{c1}
\textcolor{white}{Measure} 
        & \textcolor{white}{Description} 
                                        &   \textcolor{white}{NO.}  \\
\hline 

\rowcolor{c2}
\multirow{2}{*}{Orientation-based}    &   The first orientation-based measure is the number of empty bins in the t.  &   $N_i$ is the number of detected      \\
\cline{2-2}
& The second one is defined as the variance in  the orientations of points. & $N_i$ \\
\cline{2-2}


\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question, edit your existing one if you need to clarify it http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152684/multirow-and-multicolum-memoir