# How to split a table vertically?

Tags: tables, texmaker, linux, multicolumn

```
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
     \hline
     \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{States} \\
     \hline
     cpu &  Higher--Lower & Lower-Higher \\
     \hline
     \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Average, Standard deviation, 95\%Confidence}

%     Afghanistan    &AFG&   004\\
%     Aland Islands  &ALA   &248\\
%     Albania        &A  &08\\
%     Algeria        &DZ &012\\
%     American Samoa &ASM &016\\
%     Andorra        &AND   &020\\
%     Angola         &GO &024\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

How do I have multicolumns for higher-lower and lower-higher?

Each multicolumn in higher-lower and lower-higher will have the subcolumns, average, standard deviation, 95% confidence

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{States}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Benchmarks} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Designation}}} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Shifts}}\\
    \cline{4-7}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{G}\\
    \hline
    1 & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Plant Engineer} & & & & 1  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:pro_pro}
\end{table}
```

How do I have another column like `shifts` right next to it and remove the col: designation?

Here is the solution:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center} {\footnotesize
\scalebox{0.45}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccccccc|ccccccccc|}
\hline
Benchmarks & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Higher-Lower} 
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Lower-Higher}\\

&
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.8-1.0} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.8-1.6} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.8-2.4} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.8-1.0} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.8-1.6} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0.8-2.4}  \\ \hline

& 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confidence} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confidence} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confidence} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confidence} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confidence} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Average} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Confidence} \\ \hline

\end{tabular} }
}
\end{center}
\caption{\footnotesize P--States: PAAE and Confidence for SPECcpu2006 benchmarks.}
\label{turns}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130424/formatting-of-tables-in-latex-using-multirow-and-multicolumn-together`

This solves it. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm not sure to fully understand what you want to do. Split each of Higher--Lower and Lower--Higher columns in three subcolumns for the following rows? Youjsut have to declare 6 columns instead of 2, and use, say, `\multicolumn{3}`{c}{Higher--Lower}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Something like what say in the previous example.. How can I just have `shifts` twice.

Comment: What do you mean by `shifts`? Did you mean to write `States`?

Comment: In the link above: `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130424/formatting-of-tables-in-latex-usi‌​ng-multirow-and-multicolumn-together` I would like to repeat the col: `shifts` twice.

Comment: @Mico: Added the example

Comment: Your two sample tables appear to have very little in common. Which one are you trying to get typeset satisfactorily?

Comment: a) How do I remove column benchmarks
b) How do I have two columns. Each of which should have 4 sub columns each.